# DataTable using JQuery - edit/add/ session clarification

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, x-editable

I'm trying to do the following in JQuery and Datatable. (My first project in this area) for commercial purpose.

I get the Json data from back end and show them in a table, Now i need to

1, inline edit of any row in the data table and send that particular data to the back end (C++) which calls rest service to update in the data table. i want to know how to deal with this. i see many plugins available but most of them shows the data to be saved to a php file using Ajax. i want to send the updated DataTable as a JSON object to the back end(C++). can you please give a example for this?

2, I can't use Datatable-editor since i'm working on commercial project i need some open source plugin,i tried bootstrap for editing the datatable, but i don't want hover link on the data. is there any way to ignore this? and same doubt as above on sending son object to back end.

3, is there any way i can save datatable in the session and then retrieve it. for ex, below is the code i wrote to show the data in a datatable.

```
function populateData(items)
{
  $(document).ready(function() 
  {
      $('#tbl-results').DataTable( {
      "bProcessing": true,
       responsive: true,

       "aaData": items,
       "aoColumns": [
            { "mDataProp": "name" },
            { "mDataProp": "value" }
    ]
});
```

});
}

if i want to add/edit, i want to initialize again and then it gives issue that we can reinitialize again. what is the better way to achieve this? how to intialize one time and then add/update with the same latest Datatable object. i mean how to effectively write a code that can handle add,edit,show.. together i'm not asking any working code, but just to know the idea behind it.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: anyone to clarify my doubts???